# Media Foundation TypeLibrary for managed code?

Tags: .net, com, ms-media-foundation

Is anyone know how to generate media foundation TypeLibrary which will then be imported as COM in managed code ?
I didn't found any dll or tlb file related to media foundation which i can import in my C#.Net application.

Comment: you can use the MIDL compiler to generate a tlb file from the idl files in the windows sdk include directory. after that you can use tlbimp to generate a managed dll for the COM interfaces.

Comment: Managed wrapper for MF http://mfnet.sourceforge.net